# Introducing new distribution, notation question

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, notation

I am reading a text dealing with jump processes. Such a process is defined by its intensity and distribution $\zeta(\mathrm{d}x)$ on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ - jump height distribution. In one place we start defining new, scaled jump height distribution by:
$$\zeta^{\epsilon}(\mathrm{d}x)=\zeta\Bigg(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\Bigg).$$

What does that notation mean exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this convention simply means, that for any measurable $f$ we have
$$\int_{0}^{t}f(x)\zeta\Bigg(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\Bigg)=\int_{0}^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}}f(y\cdot\sqrt{\epsilon})\zeta(\mathrm{dy),}$$
so the size of jumps simply shrinks proportional to $1/\sqrt{\epsilon}.$